# How do I fetch data for app users offline / nightly?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, ruby, hubexchange

I want to build a Salesforce Marketing Cloud HubExchange app.  The app will schedule a task periodically to process recent event tracking data for each user in the installed base.

How do I access event data for a specific user?  What tokens or FuelSDK::Client parameters (I am using the Ruby FuelSDK, ideally) do I need to set?

I think I need to refresh the token from the JWT, but the FuelSDK::Client seems to want a JWT, not an oauth token.

Is there a code example or description for this process?

Relevant links:

- https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Ruby
- https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/marketing-cloud-apps/single-sign-on.html
- [Refresh Token request returning Unauthorized](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47138/refresh-token-request-returning-unauthorized/57668#57668)
- [ExactTarget ClientID and ClientSecret for HubExchange App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49573/exacttarget-clientid-and-clientsecret-for-hubexchange-app?rq=1)
- [How do I contextualize the Fuel SDK to retrieve event data for a specific user?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75444/how-do-i-contextualize-the-fuel-sdk-to-retrieve-event-data-for-a-specific-user/96655#96655)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution is painful and complex, but I have nothing better.  Not sure why this isn't well-trod ground, but... here goes.

- Build a database table to user store token data.
- Use my [fork of FuekSDK-Ruby](https://github.com/Vestorly/FuelSDK-Ruby) that supports a callback when the client chooses to refresh the token, and another when the refresh fails.
- Initialize the database data from data in the JWT passed by the user.
- Create the FuelSDK client with callback (and cache it, so you don't keep remaking them) and make it retry a few times if it ever has problems because someone else refreshed first.

See the attached gist for an implementation: https://gist.github.com/ses4j/6b38cd7bb391e8f41912

Answer (score 1):

The Fuel Ruby SDK will create a client using:

```
myClient = FuelSDK::Client.new {'client' => { 'id' => CLIENTID, 'secret' => SECRET }}
```

The `jwt` is optional if you have it, for distributed apps - you would need to store the access token, and the refresh token in a data store to allow your app to grab the data it needs without a user login required during the update.

Comment: So, can/should I store the whole JWT in a database field so I can use it later?  Are there pieces of it I should store, or need to refresh before storing?

Comment: You could store the entire jwt, or the current access token and refresh token. Refresh tokens don't expire so if access token is expired just refresh.

Comment: The API I need (get/set subscriber info) seems to use the legacyOauthtoken rather than the "main" access token.  Does that also need refresh?  Or can I just store that token indefinitely, and stuff it onto the myClient like `myClient.internal_token = exacttarget_internal_oauth_token`?

Comment: http://www.kellyjandrews.com/2014/02/20/using-fuel-oauth-with-the-soap-api.html will help you use the access token, and not the legacy token.

Comment: Updated my answer to account for my misreading your question.

Comment: Just read your blog post - Interesting, but how do I do that within the Ruby FuelSDK library?  I didn't make the SOAP packet, the library did, and it used the legacy token.  Anyway, I don't understand what's wrong with the legacy token ... it seems easier to use and I don't have to refresh it.  I guess it's a security-related thing?

Comment: Legacy token has issues, and occasionally fails. The Fuel SDK would need to be modified if it doesn't accept the access token already.

Comment: Is there any blog posts or documentation so I can understand the nature of it's "issues and fails"?  Is modifying the FuelSDK something ExactTarget plans to do?

Comment: Nothing out there really - it's just inconsistent. Feel free to use it as is - maybe you won't experience any issues.  The entire set of SDKs will eventually be redone - but not sure when.  Updating the current library is a community supported effort.

Comment: Is there any new information on either when the SDKs will be redone or about the inconsistency of the legacy token?  Occasionally when trying to do a refreshToken, it fails and we lose connectivity until we login and are reissued a fresh JWT.  Is that related to what you were describing?

Comment: I don't work for Salesforce any longer - but maybe someone from there will see this and comment?